# php require_once "FILENAME" causing Failed opening required ''

Tags: php, zend-framework

In .php I have this:

```
Line 64  require_once 'Zend/View/Stream.php'
```

in apache error log I see:
 [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.........

I've been googleing and debugging four hours.. Maybe this sounds familiar to someone.. 
I dont understand how code line

```
require_once 'Zend/View/Stream.php'
```

cause

```
Failed opening required ''
```

Comment: If you're using zend framework you should be using their autoloader. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html, or http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-autoloader.html

Comment: @MikeB An autoloader isn't, or shouldn't, be required in zf1. That's not the way zf1 works. It uses require_once statement to require everything.

Comment: @BullfrogBlues Everyone who cares about performance removes the require_onces in favor of the autoloader (hopefully with a cached class map). It's even documented http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/performance.classloading.html#performance.classloading.striprequires.sed

Comment: @MikeB That isn't the point. It's supposed to work without autoloading, but doesn't.

Comment: @BullfrogBlues Show me how to recreate error with anything but `<?php require_once '';`

Comment: @MikeB :)))) that would be a different issue altogether. It's mostly probably an APC issue https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61854.

Comment: @user1283791 are you using APC? And what version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* According to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62398, there was a bug in some earlier versions of APC extension with PHP 5.4 which replaced the file passed to `require` with an empty string.

Thanks to @conceptdeluxe, who figured this out when using PHP 5.4.30 with APC 3.1.13. 
A possible resolution has be confirmed to be about enabling APC via configuration directive `apc.stat=1` (in `php.ini`) or upgrading PHP and extensions.

Otherwise

You might want to update the `include_path` configuration option by following instructions available at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-include-path.php

Basically, the interpreter needs to be told where to look for the `Zend` classes.

Let us assume, `Zend` library is available from `/var/www/my_project/vendor/Zend` then we could make the next call before using `Zend Stream`:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/my_project/vendor');
```

Another solution would consist in altering the PHP configuration file
by updating the `include_path` value as follow:

```
# assuming vim is available as text editor 
# and PHP configuration file would be available for editing
vim /etc/php.ini

# append /var/www/my_project/vendor to the value of entry
include_path='.:/var/www/my_project/vendor'
```

Comment: I don't think the inlcude path is the issue. See https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/pull/874#issuecomment-49644719 ; this is a similar issue with nginx + full source of the actual code. Also, if the include path was the issue, in a full app code execution would never get to loading the zend view class.

Comment: @BullfrogBlues, you're probably right. However, there is no indication of having the `include_path` value property set in order to have the call to `require_once` working. That's why, I believe we still need to hear from @user1283791 first about this.

Comment: y. Still, if the include_path is set properly the error message won't be failing to open `''` i.e. a blank string. Rather it should be something along of lines of `Failed opening required 'Zend/View/Stream.php'`.

Comment: @BullfrogBlues, I have the feeling we might never hear from the question owner again :/ Have you encountered the exact same issue? With reference to the gist mentioned at https://gist.github.com/jyentechempower/116a881d466f77460111, isn't it simply related to the fact that `include_path` contains `:.:`?

Comment: @Thierry_Marianne No, take a [look at these error logs](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/pull/874#issuecomment-50178586). I thought that might be the case, so I refactored and now it [sets the include path directly](https://github.com/gerardroche/FrameworkBenchmarks/commit/1017b2ad8fa773b40c81d4402b26d278fcc6411d).

Comment: @BullfrogBlues Ok, I got it (at last :P). The reasoning involving possible cache issues could make sense. Have you tried to execute [clearstatcache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58390/discussion-between-bullfrogblues-and-thierry-marianne).